# Should I share my ViewModel across two fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm, android-architecture-lifecycle

I'm attempting to follow Android best practices and use the latest recommended architecture components. You can see my attempt so far here: https://github.com/randroid88/TodayILearned

Right now the app's features are very limited.

- It has a Room db for locally storing journal entries.
- One fragment, [HomeFragment](https://github.com/randroid88/TodayILearned/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/winf/todayilearned/HomeFragment.kt),  that lists all the entries
- Another fragment, [EntryEditorFragment](https://github.com/randroid88/TodayILearned/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/winf/todayilearned/EntryEditorFragment.kt), that creates new entries.
- A ViewModel,
  [EntryViewModel](https://github.com/randroid88/TodayILearned/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/winf/todayilearned/EntryViewModel.kt), that updates the data via a repository.

The problem is that only HomeFragment has access to EntryViewModel right now.

So in my current design, I pass the new entry text from EntryEditorFragment to HomeFragment via an argument bundle (using [SafeArgs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#7) from the new Navigation Architecture Component), then HomeFragment creates the new entry via the EntryViewModel:

```
val safeArgs = HomeFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!)
    savePossibleNewEntry(safeArgs.entryText)

private fun savePossibleNewEntry(entryText: String) {
    entryViewModel!!.insert(EntryCreator().create(entryText))
}
```

This doesn't feel right.

Would it be better if EntryViewModel also had access to EntryEditorFragment?

In order to accomplish this, would I have to scope the ViewModel to the Activity as explained here [on this blog](https://medium.com/a-problem-like-maria/a-problem-like-navigation-part-2-63e46a565d4b)?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: It does look like the official documentation recommends sharing the ViewModel: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing_data_between_fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing_data_between_fragments) suggested sharing a ViewModel for "a common case of master-detail fragments" so I decided to do the same for my case.

As suggested, I scoped the ViewModel to the Activity in both fragments:

```
entryViewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, EntryViewModelFactory(this.application, EntryRepository(this.application))).get(EntryViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

Here's the commit where I made the change:
https://github.com/randroid88/TodayILearned/commit/e307bd3f238e68a399a2a1619438770d908a606d